# How do I use aggregate function and CASE WHEN THEN in SELECT query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

1. sales_fact (fact_date, prod_id, fact_sum)
2. sales_pred (pred_date, prod_id, pred_sum)
3. product (prod_id, name, price)

I need to make up a **report** which consists of the following **columns**:
Year
Month
Name of the product
Fact sales
Predicted saled
Deviation

If **Fact sales is null**, then deviation = Predicted saled;
If **Predicted saled** is null, then deviation = -Fact sales

I have difficulties in the last condition. Help me to understand my mistake

My code:

```
SELECT year(fact_date) AS Year, 
        month(fact_date) AS Month,  
        product.name AS Name, 
        ROUND(SUM(fact_sum), 2) AS Fact, 
        ROUND(SUM(pred_sum), 2) AS Prediction, 
        (CASE 
             WHEN SUM(pred_sum) IS NULL AND SUM(fact_sum) IS NOT NULL 
             THEN ROUND(-(SUM(fact_sum)), 2)
             WHEN SUM(fact_sum) IS NULL AND SUM(pred_sum) IS NOT NULL
             THEN ROUND(SUM(pred_sum)), 2)
             WHEN SUM(pred_sum) IS NOT NULL AND SUM(fact_sum) IS NOT NULL
             THEN ROUND(SUM(pred_sum) - (SUM(fact_sum)), 2) 
             ELSE 0 END AS Deviation        
FROM sales_fact
LEFT JOIN product ON sales_fact.prod_id = product.prod_id
LEFT JOIN sales_pred ON sales_pred.prod_id = product.prod_id AND sales_pred.pred_date = sales_fact.fact_date
GROUP BY product.name, month(fact_date), year(fact_date);
```

CODE FOR CREATING TABLES:

```
create table sales_fact (fact_date date, prod_id varchar(30), fact_sum float);
    insert into sales_fact (fact_date, prod_id, fact_sum) values ('2016-03-25', '2271145', 93.31);
    insert into sales_fact (fact_date, prod_id, fact_sum) values ('2016-04-25', '2271146', 13.31);
    insert into sales_fact (fact_date, prod_id, fact_sum) values ('2016-05-25', '2271147', 83.31);
    insert into sales_fact (fact_date, prod_id, fact_sum) values ('2016-03-25', '2271145', 43.31);
    insert into sales_fact (fact_date, prod_id, fact_sum) values ('2016-07-25', '2271148', 73.31);
    insert into sales_fact (fact_date, prod_id, fact_sum) values ('2016-07-25', '2271147', 13.31);
    insert into sales_fact (fact_date, prod_id, fact_sum) values ('2016-08-25', '2271149', 43.31);
    insert into sales_fact (fact_date, prod_id, fact_sum) values ('2016-09-25', '2271148', 33.31);
create table sales_pred (pred_date date, prod_id varchar(30), pred_sum float);
    insert into sales_pred (pred_date, prod_id, pred_sum) values ('2016-03-25', '2271145', 100);
    insert into sales_pred (pred_date, prod_id, pred_sum) values ('2016-04-25', '2271146', 93.31);
    insert into sales_pred (pred_date, prod_id, pred_sum) values ('2016-05-25', '2271147', 103.31);
    insert into sales_pred (pred_date, prod_id, pred_sum) values ('2016-07-25', '2271148', 73.31);
create table product (prod_id varchar(30), name varchar(30), price float);
    insert into product (prod_id, name, price) values ('2271145', 'phone', 3);   
    insert into product (prod_id, name, price) values ('2271147', 'laptop', 4);
    insert into product (prod_id, name, price) values ('2271148', 'PC', 5);
    insert into product (prod_id, name, price) values ('2271146', 'mouse', 2);
    insert into product (prod_id, name, price) values ('2271149', 'airpods', 7);
```

Comment: *I have 3 tables* You must provide complete CREATE TABLE for the tables - this is critical for the question.

Comment: Please provide few sample data.

Comment: It looks like you are treating NULL as zero, which is not usually correct.  If you have null values that should be zero, you are better off fixing them to be zero.  If they shouldn't be zero then Deviation probably should return NULL if there is a null value in the calculation.

Comment: PS. `ROUND(SUM(pred_sum) - SUM(fact_sum), 2)` <> `ROUND(SUM(pred_sum), 2) - ROUND(SUM(fact_sum), 2)`.

Comment: Simply use `COALESCE`, then you don't need a `CASE` at all eg `COALESCE(SUM(pred_sum),0) - COALESCE(SUM(fact_sum),0)`

Comment: @YekaterinaMikhalchuk if pred_sum - fact_sum is negative then what will show. Both are NOT NULL in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As per your condition deviation can be negative so use simply subtract and use colaesce() for converting NULL values to 0(zero).

```
-- MySQL
SELECT YEAR(sf.fact_date) year
     , MONTH(sf.fact_date) month
     , p.name
     , COALESCE(ROUND(SUM(sf.fact_sum), 2), 0) fact
     , COALESCE(ROUND(SUM(slp.pred_sum), 2), 0) Prediction
     , ROUND(COALESCE(SUM(slp.pred_sum), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(sf.fact_sum), 0), 2) deviation
FROM sales_fact sf
LEFT JOIN product p 
       ON sf.prod_id = p.prod_id
LEFT JOIN sales_pred slp
       ON slp.prod_id = p.prod_id 
      AND slp.pred_date = sf.fact_date
GROUP BY YEAR(sf.fact_date), MONTH(sf.fact_date), p.name;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9e9f21dd36400d8830a4734aa7ffb29

Comment: If deviation has to be positive then `ABS()` is simpler. As you pointed out though, the OP is unclear/illogical on this. According to OP code if both sums have values then a negative can arise. If the prediction is null, it makes no logical sense then to show a positive amount. To always have deviation as a positive would produce a pretty meaningless number, because you don't know if it is surplus or deficit.

Comment: BTW if you write an answer that basically elaborates on someone else's comments, it is usually considered polite to acknowledge the fact.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanWillcock for you observation. Yes ABS() is better. It would be better if questioner provided expected output. Need response from questioner.